# libvorbis complains "more samples than frame size"

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, vorbis

I am trying to figure out what's wrong with my command to encode into theora+vorbis. I am able to demonstrate the issue with minimum code as following:

encoding audio followed by video works ok:

```
ffmpeg -filter_complex "smptehdbars=size=1280x720:rate=30000/1001[v];sine=beep_factor=2[a]" -map [a] -map [v] -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis -t 3 -f ogg map-audio-video.ogg -y
```

however video followed by audio does not work (swapped order of -map):

```
ffmpeg -filter_complex "smptehdbars=size=1280x720:rate=30000/1001[v];sine=beep_factor=2[a]" -map [v] -map [a] -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis -t 3 -f ogg map-video-audio.ogg -y
```

and fails with the following error:

```
ffmpeg version 4.4-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
Stream mapping:
  smptehdbars -> Stream #0:0 (libtheora)
  sine -> Stream #0:1 (libvorbis)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libvorbis @ 000001f846602fc0] more samples than frame size
Audio encoding failed
Conversion failed!
```

Any idea why the standard order video, audio breaks on samples vs. frame size?

Answer (score 1):

Use `-f lavfi` to indicate that the following inputs are filters. Because you have two distinct inputs use two `-f lavfi`.

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i "smptehdbars=size=1280x720:rate=30000/1001" -f lavfi -i "sine=beep_factor=2" -c:v libtheora -c:a libvorbis -t 3 output.ogg
```

Comment: Thanks llogan, I managed to modify your script (as I needed labeled streams for furhter filtering):

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i "smptehdbars=size=1280x720:rate=30000/1001" -f lavfi -i "sine=beep_factor=2" -filter_complex "[0:v]null[v];[1:a]anull[a]" -map [v] -map [a] -c:v libtheora -c:a libvorbis -t 3 lavfi.ogg
```

Do you have any idea why the original did not work and one has to explicitly set two inputs via explicit -f lavfi inputs. Shouldnt these two be approaches produce same data flow inside ffmpeg?

Comment: @Yoz I only had a solution in mind and did not take the time to investigate the cause of the problem.